# Use Case : <<extend>> or not?

Tags: modeling, use-case

i got a system (a videogame) and an use case (attack) . If the opponent is attacked and he's not online, he receive an email else he doesn't.

I don't know if it's better make one use case:

```
USR----(ATTACK)<-------<< extends >>---(OFFLINE-ATTACK)----MAIL SERVER
```

or

```
USR----(ATTACK)------MAIL SERVER
```

Answer (score 1):

Each usecase should represent an actor's goal. (OFFLINE-ATTACK) does not sound like an actual valid goal but more like an exception (alternative path).

Comment: i think the same too, i managed it as a subvariation, the goal is to show the attack button disabled, and show a message "end of the shift".